# XSLT following-sibling output not as expected

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I want to get all elements between the first sale and the next sale.
Initial XML

```
<Parent>
    <Sale SeqNo="1"/>
    <Discount SeqNo="2"/>
    <Coupon SeqNo="4"/>
    <CouponDetail SeqNo="5"/>
    <Sale SeqNo="6"/>
    <Sale SeqNo="7"/>
    <Sale SeqNo="8"/>
    <Payment SeqNo="9"/>
</Parent>
```

Desired XML:

```
<Discount SeqNo="2"/>
<Coupon SeqNo="4"/>
<CouponDetail SeqNo="5"/>
```

I currently have the following applying to a template

```
following-sibling::*[(number(@SeqNo) &lt; number(following::Sale[1]/@SeqNo))]
```

Output I am currently getting:

```
<Discount SeqNo="2"/>
<Coupon SeqNo="4"/>
<CouponDetail SeqNo="5"/>
<Sale SeqNo="6"/>
<Sale SeqNo="7"/>
<Sale SeqNo="8"/>
<Payment SeqNo="9"/>
```

If I hardcode in the sequence number of the next sale item I get the correct output

```
following-sibling::*[(number(@SeqNo) &lt; number(6))]
```

Output:

```
<Discount SeqNo="2"/>
<Coupon SeqNo="4"/>
<CouponDetail SeqNo="5"/>
```

What am i missing? 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the context in which your predicate is being evaluated - it's the particular element child of `Parent` that is being tested for whether it should be included in the resulting node-set.  So in that context, `following::Sale[1]` gives you the first `Sale` element following the element being tested, which will always have a higher `@SeqNo`, even if it is itself a `Sale` element.

What you need to do is store the sequence number of interest in an `xsl:variable` prior to doing your select, for instance:

```
<xsl:variable name="end_seq_no" select="following-sibling::Sale[1]/@SeqNo"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[@SeqNo &lt; $end_seq_no]"/>
```

Comment: Or if you don't want the variable, use `current()` to access the outer context from within the predicate: `following-sibling::*[@SeqNo &lt; current()/following-sibling::Sale[1]/@SeqNo]`

Comment: @IanRoberts I can't see that function even in [XPath 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/). Where is it defined?

Comment: The `current()` function is part of the XSLT spec, not the xpath one.